# Angular HashLocationStrategy includes directory name

Tags: angular

Angular version 9.0;

The web application is deployed in the directory 
 `/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/`

`APP_BASE_HREF` is set to `/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/` in *app.module.ts*

```
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ /*...*/ ],
  imports: [/*...*/],
  providers: [{
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF, 
      useValue: "/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/"
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [/*...*/]
})
```

Now adds `settings` in routing, `HashLocationStrategy` is enabled.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';

const routes: Routes =  [
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Everything works fine except that the URL appears in web browser address bar is 
[image]

**Current** : `http://127.0.0.1:4200/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/#/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/settings`

**Wanted** : `http://127.0.0.1:4200/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/#/settings`

Is there a way to make it show as above but still hosting in `/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/` folder?

Comment: after hosting you are getting like this

Answer (score 0):

whatever you can see in the URL is correct and it will work in that way actually,

URL is formed as

```
https(or)https://domainName/BaseRef/#/your routing paths
```

If you want URL to be like

```
https(or)https://domainName/#/your routing paths
```

give basehref as "/" and deployURl as "642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6" or folder name while building: example

```
ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href / --deploy-url /642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/
```

your base URL will be `/` that means your URL looks like `http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/settings`

that means index.html will be in the main folder and you should place scripts in the folder name you have given while building(parameter of --deploy-url)

Comment: I didn't make myself clear enough,  I want to keep base url with `/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/`,   But I want angular shows `http://127.0.0.1:4200/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/#/settings`

Comment: it is very simple then give base-href as /642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/ and give deploy-url as /642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/ and move all javascript generated file to that folder leave index.html outside folder

Comment: Hi @Ravi ,    the deploy path is " /642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/" as well.. In short, the files are deployed in directory.   But the url show in URL hashing path do not include the folder.

Comment: Hi @Mr.WangfromNextDoor can I know where is the index.html file respective to `642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6` folder

Comment: Hi @Ravi, `https://domainname/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/index.html`.
I wanna make the URL appears in address as :

`https://domainname/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/#/home`  instead of 
`https://domainname/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/#/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/home`.

Comment: HI @Mr.WangfromNextDoor, can you please delete dist folder and execute `ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href https://domainname/642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/ --deploy-url /642f57951edd412f9da095801e657cc6/`  then deploy dist folder

Comment: Thanks @Ravi, I have to configure `APP_BASE_HREF` on the fly because the folder name is randomized.

Comment: Tried to create an example in StackBlitz but failed. seems it does not support sub-directory